# Firebase refresh token - on clear app data

Tags: android, mobile, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am calling firebase onTokenRefresh() token. From Firebase site I understand that token deletes if we clear the app data.

- When is the token created again if we clear app data.
- Can we send push notifications if we are not logged in after clearing app data.

Comment: token refreshed when app again opens

Comment: as long as fcm token valid, you app receive notification despite of login or logout

Comment: "Can we send push notifications if we are not logged in after clearing app data?" So you mean it is a 'no' for this question

Comment: if you clear app data and does not open app . then you can not receive notifictaion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token will be generated once the app is installed,If want to use the token even after the app is cleared, you can get it by

```
      FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); ----> this will return only in authorised login.
```